# What is an efficiant way to only set the time portion of a Date using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date-fns

With a given date and string :

```
const currentDate = new Date();   // today
const currentTime = "16:30:00";
```

How can I efficiently set `currentTime` to `currentDate`?

A naive approach would be to format and parse, but it seems quite inefficient

```
const nextDate = parseISO(format(currentDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd') + 'T' + currentTime);
```

Comment: There's the [`set`](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/set) function from date-fns. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Wing no, because the `time` portion is a string, not an object, like `set` expects

Comment: Right, I see. What's the measure of efficiency? You really have two options: convert your date into a string, join it with the time string and convert it all back into a date; or convert your time string into something usable with date-fns APIs (or even native date APIs) to set the time on the date object. I think either way is a micro-optimisation that you'd only really make once you're reaching the boundaries of performance.

Comment: I figured. I'm currently using the format+concat+parse approach right now, but my OCD is annoyed at this. :)

Comment: I just had some fun with a benchmarker and found getting date components and joining strings then returning a new date significantly faster (more than 50%) than splitting the time string and using native date APIs to set the time components. It's not completely representative since I wasn't using date-fns but native date APIs. However it might reduce worries that your implementation is inefficient. I would share a URL but the benchmarker encodes the code in the URL which makes it way too long to put in a comment and this finding doesn't really fit an answer.

Comment: @Wing thank you for that information! Eventually, ECMA specs will get to the `Date` API and perhaps JS will finally have a proper `DateTime` API.